# in Neo4j my Cypher query pulls data from most recently loaded object, not the one specified

Tags: neo4j

I believe this code demonstrates a bug in this software.  But given my lack of experience with Neo4j, maybe something is coded incorrectly.

I would like to know if the unexpected output is due to a bug.

Given 2 tiny **.csv** files, I load these data and when I query each loaded object the data seems ok.

Then when I query object **T7** it shows the data from object **T8**.

Thanks!

## Steps to reproduce the behaviour

### File t7.csv

```
col1
t7 1 row
```

### File t8.csv

```
col1
t8 2 rows
t8 2 rows
```

I then login with the following command:

```
$ bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j -p my password
```

I then run the following commands:

```
MATCH (T7)
OPTIONAL MATCH (T7)-[r]-()
WITH T7,r LIMIT 5000
DELETE T7,r
RETURN count(T7) as deletedNodesCount;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///t7.csv" as line
CREATE (T7 {col1:line.col1});

MATCH T7 = (t7)
RETURN t7.col1;
```

The above commands load the data and return the values found as follows:

> ```
> +------------+
> | a.col1     |
> +------------+
> | "t7 1 row" |
> +------------+
> ```

I perform the same task for the T8 data:

```
MATCH (T8)
OPTIONAL MATCH (T8)-[r]-()
WITH T8,r LIMIT 5000
DELETE T8,r
RETURN count(T8) as deletedNodesCount;

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///t8.csv" as line
CREATE (T8 {col1:line.col1});

MATCH T8 = (t8)
RETURN t8.col1;
```

The above commands load the data and return the values found as follows:

> ```
> +-------------+
> | a.col1      |
> +-------------+
> | "t8 2 rows" |
> | "t8 2 rows" |
> +-------------+
> ```

Now if I run the following command, this gets data for most recent query, but not the correct node?

```
MATCH T7 = (t7)
RETURN t7.col1;
```

I expected this output:

> ```
> +------------+
> | a.col1     |
> +------------+
> | "t7 1 row" |
> +------------+
> ```

Instead I received the following output:

> ```
> +-------------+
> | a.col1      |
> +-------------+
> | "t8 2 rows" |
> | "t8 2 rows" |
> +-------------+
> ```

### Version information

#### Neo4j

```
call dbms.components() yield name, versions, edition unwind versions as version return name, version, edition;
```

> ```
> +----------------------------------------+
> | name           | version | edition     |
> +----------------------------------------+
> | "Neo4j Kernel" | "3.5.1" | "community" |
> +----------------------------------------+
> ```

#### OS

Mac OS 10.13.6

Comment: I've heavily redacted your question to increase readability. If you believe I have missed something or misinterpreted your question, then please do [edit] it wherever you feel necessary.